# sq server 2008 усечение символьных данных

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица `tblTovar` с колонкой `tovar_name (nvarchar 50)`.

Есть ли способ разрешения на усечение этой колонке при вводе символов больше 50.

Спасибо!!

Comment: "способ разращения на усечение" - уточните, что Вы имеете в виду...

Comment: у меня при вставке на поле tovar_name значении длина которые больше 50 символов sql server дает ошибку. как сделать так что бы запредельные символы sql server сам вырезал ?

Comment: `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`

Comment: Извиняюсь за офтоп: В Чернобыле 30 лет назад тоже автоматику отключали. Все знают чем кончилось. Поэтому лучше вставляйте в процедуре с проверкой и возвратом ошибок или проверяйте размер на клиенте.

Answer (score 4):

Вам необходимо отключить оповещение при превышении длины символьного поля. Т.е. установить параметр `ANSI_WARNINGS` в значение `OFF`

Например:

```
USE MyDBName;
GO  

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;  
GO
```

[Подробнее о параметре ANSI_WARNINGS на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190368.aspx)